# In an array of 27 strings make a new array of 9 unique strings

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, processing

I'm struggling with the following problem. I am making the card game Set for my study and I am currently at the point where I have this function that makes all the cards and put them in an array of 27 strings. Next, I made a new function which takes this array as an argument, iterates through it and returns a new array with 9 unique new strings(cards). This has to be random.

The idea is that everytime I pick a string of the 27 strings array I replace this string with an empty string. At the end of the game, this array has 27 empty strings and no cards can be dealt.

My question is: with this idea, how can I prevent duplicates in this new array of 9 unique cards. The tip from school and work: do something with your random range.

So basically: When the for loop picks " ", it has to skip this so that I have 9 unique cards in the new array.

It is done in Processing (java).

This is my code:

```
String[] onScreen(String[] cards) { 

  String[] cardsToPlay = new String[9];
  int index = 0;
  int lengthArray = cards.length;

  for(int i = 0; i < cardsToPlay .length; i++) {
    int randomCard = int(random(lengthArray));
    cardsToPlay[index] = kaarten[randomCard];
    index++;
    lengthArray--;
    kaarten[randomCard] = "lege string";
  }

return cardsToPlay ;
}
```

Comment: so you want to create an array of 9 unique strings with in the same array ? and the unique string are also picked from the same array ?

Comment: Please add the language you're using as a tag to this question.

Comment: The function takes an array of 27 strings (cards) and returns a new array of 9 unique cards, picked from that array,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to remove the random card from the array `kaarten`.

With the function [`shorten()`](https://processing.org/reference/shorten_.html) the size of an array can be decreased by 1. The last element will be removed from the array.

If a `random` card was selected from the stack, then swap this card with the last card of the stack:

```java
String lastCard = kaarten[kaarten.length-1];
kaarten[kaarten.length-1] = kaarten[randomCard];
kaarten[randomCard] = lastCard;
```

Now the last card is the card which was chosen. Remove the last card from the stack:

```java
kaarten = shorten(kaarten);
```

The function `onScreen` may look like this:

```
String[] onScreen() { 

    String[] cardsToPlay = new String[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < cardsToPlay.length; i++) {

        int randomCard = int(random(kaarten.length));
        cardsToPlay[i] = kaarten[randomCard];

        String lastCard = kaarten[kaarten.length-1];
        kaarten[kaarten.length-1] = kaarten[randomCard];
        kaarten[randomCard] = lastCard;

        kaarten = shorten(kaarten);
    }
    return cardsToPlay ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A better option for you would be to run a loop for 9 iterations. Generate a random number between 1-27 and retrieve the value at that index from the array and add it to a set(To have unique values). The moment length of set reaches 9 break the loop. Later convert the set to array an of 9 elements

Comment: This could help too indeed. Thank you.